# How to change Xcode's SplitView template - tableview on the right, detail view on the left

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using XCode's splitview template.  I want the list of items to be on the right when in landscape mode - is this a quick change - can someone give me some pointers if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Gemmell's MGSplitViewController is exactly what you're looking for. It gives you complete control, is well-written, and has a generous, free license.

http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad